# Is there a way to add a hardware button (linked physically or via Bluetooth) to an iPhone 7 which allows unlocking of the phone?

Tags: smartphones, bluetooth, apple

If the iPhone 7 button has become defective and non-replaceable - is there any way a physical button can be added / connected to the iPhone so that pressing it unlocks the phone (with appropriate software additions).

This product - https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000009832310.html - serves as an external home button, but does not unlock it.

Comment: Is your iPhone rooted? It is not possible for an iOS app to programmatically lock or unlock the phone. That would be a major security hole.

Comment: Thanks @Romen - its not rooted, but if I root it, is there a software which could help with this situation?

Comment: I'm not an expert on iOS, but it seems that there is no documented API for locking or unlocking the phone, so you would have to discover how to invoke that sort of OS functionality. Maybe someone else has already done this for your specific version of iOS. I strongly advise against setting your phone up to work this way; It can entirely defeat the point of having a lock screen if you are going to implement a way for you to circumvent it at the push of a button.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any buttons that can unlock an iPhone to the best of my knowledge because it would be a security risk. However, you can pair a bluetooth keyboard to the iPhone and use the keyboard to unlock the phone. When I pair my Logitech K480 keyboard with my iPhone, it allows me to lock/unlock, type messages, take screenshots, adjust volume, and more.

I would also recommend taking a look at the app "Shortcuts" by Apple. You may find it very useful.